# Importing and Parsing KML files in GoogleMap

Tags: parsing, import, maps, kml, layer

I'm trying to use Google Maps API with new layers created directly in the Google Maps platform, and exported to a .kml file. The guide used was main one available at Google Developer's portal.

However, it seems the KML file is unable to load properly. http://1c.1contact.ch/mandats/map1.html

The code to connect and load the the map is bellow (it was adapted from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer):

```
<script>
  var map;
  var src = 'http://1c.1contact.ch/file/2573/GE.kml';

  /**
  * Initializes the map and calls the function that loads the KML layer.
  */
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
  zoom: 2,
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  loadKmlLayer(src, map);
  }

  /**
  * Adds a KMLLayer based on the URL passed. Clicking on a marker
  * results in the balloon content being loaded into the right-hand div.
  * @param {string} src A URL for a KML file.
  */
  function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  preserveViewport: false,
  map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
  var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
  var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
  testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
  }
</script>
```

What's the proper method to accomplish this .KML usage?

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

The KML file you specified (http://1c.1contact.ch/file/2573/GE.kml) won't load because it is not publicly accessible on the web.  It appears to be behind a login page on that server.  Even if you're logged in with your browser, the Google Maps code and rendering system will not have access to the file, so you need to put it somewhere publicly accessible.